# android : SoftReference / WeakReference example

Tags: android, weak-references, soft-references

I am getting `OutOfMemoryError` on my application. When i went through some tutorials, i came to  know that, I can solve this issue by using `Softreference/Weakreference`. But I don't know that how to use `Softreference/Weakreference`.

Please suggest me some tutorials that providing examples for the Softreference or Weakreference.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following tutorial

[How to use SoftReference](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue015.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers are not acceptable here.

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.myapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;


public class BitmapSoftRefrences {


      public static String SDPATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/MYAPP";

// 1. create a cache map
public static WeakHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> mCache = new WeakHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();
public static String TAG = "BitmapSoftRefrences";

// 2. ask for bitmap
public static Bitmap get(String key) {
    if (key == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        if (mCache.containsKey(key)) {

            SoftReference<Bitmap> reference = mCache.get(key);
            Bitmap bitmap = reference.get();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                return bitmap;
            }
            return decodeFile(key);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Logger.debug(BitmapSoftRefrences.class,
                "EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());

    }

    // the key does not exists so it could be that the
    // file is not downloaded or decoded yet...

    File file = new File(SDPATH + "/" + key);

    if (file.exists()) {
        return decodeFile(key);
    } else {
        Logger.debug(BitmapSoftRefrences.class, "RuntimeException");

        throw new RuntimeException("RuntimeException!");
    }
}

// 3. the decode file will return bitmap if bitmap is not cached
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String key) {
    // --- prevent scaling
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inScaled = false;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(SDPATH + "/" + key, opt);

    mCache.put(key, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));

    return bitmap;
}

public static void clear() {
    mCache.clear();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a `WeakReference`, the syntax is `WeakReference<SomeType> myWeakReference = new WeakReference<SomeType>(actualObject);`.  To retrieve the object via that `WeakReference`, do the check `if (weakWidget == null)`.  That way, you will avoid a `NullPointerException` if it has been garbage-collected already.

[This Java.net article by Ethan Nicholas](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html) explains *why* you would want to use a `WeakReference` instead of a strong one.  It provides the example of a `final` (unextendible) class called `Widget` that has no defined serial UID, presuming that the developer decides to define a serial UID to track each `Widget` instance.  They do so by creating a new `HashMap` and doing something like `serialNumberMap.put(widget, widgetSerialNumber);` which is a strong reference.  That means it must be explicitly cleaned up when no longer needed.  The developer is responsible for knowing exactly when to manually "garbage-collect" that reference and remove it from the `HashMap`, which should be done only when they're *really* sure it's not needed anymore.  This may be the problem you ran into in your application.

In this particular case, as the article explains, the developer could use the `WeakHashMap` class instead (as @NayAneshGupte put in his example), wherein the key is actually a `WeakReference`.  This would allow the JVM nullify the keys to old `Widget`s as it saw fit, so that the garbage collector could come along and destroy their associated objects.

The article also goes on to talk about `SoftReferences` and `PhantomReferences` (which I've never used).  You can read more about all of these in [this javapapers.com article](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-weak-reference/) and [this Rally blog](http://www.rallydev.com/community/engineering/java-references-strong-soft-weak-phantom).

Comment: @CodyGray--ironically, the original accepted answer was also a link. While you definitely have a point (and I had not realized it when answering this originally), even the thread you referenced reveals varying opinions about whether a link can be a good answer in and of itself. To that end, would it have been acceptable for me to have posted this as a comment on another answer (instead of as an answer)?

Comment: I left the same comment on the original post—link-only answers are not acceptable answers, whether someone else does it first or not. The better solution would have been to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for reference. Yes, you could have left a comment, but that's not the same thing as an answer.

Comment: Anybody like my answer better, now that I've revised it?  :)